# Using iota in a function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to create a function $f \in \mathbb{N}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ which returns the highest number $x$ so that $2^x$ is smaller then some number $n$. As this function should return the single highest integer satisfying said conditions, I thought about using iota to denote the single output which the function should have, like so:

$$f = \lambda n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}. (\iota x)(2^x \lt n \wedge \forall m \in \mathbb{N}.(2^m \lt n) \rightarrow(m \le x))$$

I am unsure whether this is a proper formal representation of what I'm looking for, and if not, then how should I formulate this function?

Comment: Strictly smaller ?

Comment: Ah yes. Although I don't think it matters that much. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can be defined as

$$f(n):=2^{\lceil\log_2 n\rceil-1}.$$

If we keep some freedom about strict equality, a more natural definition would be
$$f(n):=2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}.$$

If I had to intensively use it in a text, I would probably use the notation

$$(n)_2$$ with an explicit definition. (Because that reminds of an alternative notation for the floor, $[n]$, and specifies the radix.)

A $\iota$ would mean nothing to me.

Answer (score 1):

> $f = \lambda n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}. (\iota x)(2^x < n \wedge \forall m \in \mathbb{N}.(2^m < n) \rightarrow(m \le x))$

Your formulation should probably be fine with people knowing about $\lambda$ and $\iota$.

Some alternatives below. Let $A(n, x)$ denote $2^x < n\wedge\forall m\in\mathbb N.(2^m < n\to m\le x)$.

1. You can state that the graph of $f$ is $$\{(n,x)\mid n\in\mathbb N^+\wedge x\in\mathbb N\wedge A(n,x)\},$$ and $f = (\text{graph},\mathbb N^+,\mathbb N)$.
2. You can also write informally (after $f\colon\mathbb N^+\to\mathbb N$) that $f(n) = x\leftrightarrow A(n,x)$. It’s not bad only because it’s partly informal, and it generally means (1).

Either of three mentioned ways, ideally, you also have to prove functionality of relation $A$.

EDIT: made the answer consistent with updated OP’s definition.